# Getting specific image coordinate by noise filtering

Tags: image-processing, noise-reduction

I have a set of images that all together telling some information about my research. The problem is that the image has a lot of noise that I want to filter out and can't find out how[image]

In the image above I want to get the indexes (or values) of only the white strip, Someone adviced me to do it with machine learning but I wonder if there is a more straight forward method.

Edit.
added image as request
[image]

Comment: Can you add a further image please, for me to try some ideas on?

Comment: How can these two images be from the same project? They are nothing like each other?